# Finding and replacing a Substring using Regex

Tags: regex, excel, replace

I`m trying to replace the substring "AV-" in a String using Regex for Excel . I created the folowing function but it does not find or replace the match

```
Sub simpleRegex()
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[AV-]{AV-}"
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = "ZS-"
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strInput As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & (ActiveCell.Row))

If strPattern <> "" Then
    strInput = Myrange.Value
    strReplace = ""

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("E" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = (regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace))
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not matched")
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: I assume you are trying something to learn, because this can be done with one line in vba `Myrange.Replace "AV-", "ZS-", xlPart, , True`

Comment: Its hard to say what is the input / output requirement are but you could use something like this 
 `ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "(AV-)(.*)", "ZS-$2-TRAILING", RegexOptions.Multiline)` or something that Scott have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want to do without sample input/output.  However, if you just want to replace the string "AV-" with "ZS-", your pattern should be "AV-".

Also, in case you're not aware, there are regex tester sites that help you create/test your regex patterns because complex ones can get pretty unreadable.  One site that I'd recommend would be https://regex101.com/.  Keep in mind that the different languages' implementation of regex are not identical, but it should at least help you get close.

Comment: Well yes that's basically what I'm trying to do. Thanks a million, and for the link.